# Select statement to show next 'event' in the future

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to retrieve the record of the next upcoming event, i have used a variety of different methods, but cannot seem to get the result. I need the event that is retrieved to be in the future,

For example if there was an event yesterday and there is one in three weeks time, i would like the record of the one in three weeks time, rather than yesterday.

The statement i have currently is:

```
SELECT TOP 1    *
FROM            Events
WHERE           StartDate <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,getdate()), 0)
ORDER BY        StartDate ASC
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 E.* 
FROM Events E 
WHERE E.StartDate > GetDate()
ORDER BY E.StartDate ASC
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx